# How to use count with Distinct ON

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this query that already works, i need to write count query for this (need pagination), and i have issues using count with DISTINCT ON, anyone knows correct syntax and way to use it, i already googled but was not able to find any count queries with DISTINCT ON

As result i'm expecting total number of rows from this query that already works

```
select DISTINCT on (csd.team_contest_id)
        c.id as contestId
            from contest as c
            left join company_sponsor_team as csd on csd.contest_id = c.id
            left join sponsor as s on s.id = c.sponsor_id
            left join team as d on d.id = c.team_id
            left join player as m on c.creator_id = m.id
            WHERE c.id = c.id 
            AND ((c.team_id is not null and c.sponsor_id is null and lower(d.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%TAN%')))
            OR (c.team_id is not null and c.sponsor_id is not null and lower(s.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%TAN%')))
            OR (c.team_id is null and lower(s.name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%TAN%')))) AND (CURRENT_DATE < c.archive_date)
```

Comment: What results are you looking for?

Comment: as result i'm expecting total number of rows from result

Comment: count(distinct(whateverfieldyouwant) the rest of the query is the same, select (count(distinct(whatever...))) , otherfields from sometable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to count the number of rows, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from ( <your query here> ) x;
```

If you have an aversion to subqueries, you can always do:

```
select count(distinct csd.team_contest_id)
from . . .  <the rest of your query here>;
```

This returns the same value assuming that `csd.team_contest_id` is not `NULL`.